# What does SQLEXPR Installer return code -2068578304 mean?

Tags: inno-setup, sql-server-express

I am working on an installer project where we are replacing an old WISE based installer with innosetup.

One of the install scripts that is being ported to the new installer kicks of SQLEXPR.exe which is SQL Server Express.

During testing some computers get %ERRORLEVEL% = -2068578304

A bit of googling and I have been unable to work out the exact meaning.  This is not in the range of error codes produced by MSI based installers.  Does anyone have any idea what the cause of error here is and how to correctly parse it?  I am seeing other large negative error codes that can be split into multiple pieces. e.g. exit code and facility code?  any ideas?

After finding the log file, I've found a bit more info.  And when converting that number to hex I can now see the problem.  The batch file that is used to kick off the SQL Server Express installation is treating the result as a 32bit number but it's really a 16bit one.  So if I mask -2068578304 to 0xffffffff
I will get the result 0x84b40000.  The script looks currently looks at the bottom 4 bits to determine error or success (this is zero) so the question now becomes what does the Facility Code mean?  as it appears it largely installed but the default instance is missing.

I guess I'm really wanting to know what values Facility Code can be returned.  Our installation script is just looking at ErrorCode but that is not enough in other words.  Is there a list of descriptions somewhere for FacilityCode?

Update:
It turns out that this is a problem with SQL2012 and earlier that the actual ErrorCode is not propagated to the SQLEXPR return code.  It should really return the inner result 0x851a0013.  SQL2014 and newer does the right thing.

```
Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to inner
most order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingValidatio
nException
    Message:
        The specified sa password does not meet strong password requirements. Fo
r more information about strong password requirements, see "Database Engine Conf
iguration - Account Provisioning" in Setup Help or in SQL Server 2012 Books Onli
ne.
    HResult : 0x84b40000
        FacilityCode : 1204 (4b4)
        ErrorCode : 0 (0000)
    Data:
      SQL.Setup.FailureCategory = InputSettingValidationFailure
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack:
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.LogAll
ValidationErrorsAndThrowFirstOne(ValidationState vs)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.ValidateFeatureSetti
ngsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String acti
onId, TextWriter errorStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteAc
tionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun, ServiceContain
er context)
    Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.Validation
Exception
        Message:
                The specified sa password does not meet strong password requirem
ents. For more information about strong password requirements, see "Database Eng
ine Configuration - Account Provisioning" in Setup Help or in SQL Server 2012 Bo
oks Online.
        HResult : 0x851a0013
                FacilityCode : 1306 (51a)
                ErrorCode : 19 (0013)
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Charlieface - I've updated the question with more detail

Comment: I might be missing something, but isn't that message the real problem: *"The specified sa password does not meet strong password requirements"*? Maybe check the [answer from Johan Wrettinger here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3b64f683-33c1-458d-8ee2-722f16e4c56a/the-sa-password-must-meet-sql-server-password-policy-requirements?forum=sqlsecurity). The `sa` account is short for system administrator and is necessary to access the system databases that are installed - especially the master database.

Comment: Looks like the `setup.exe` switch to set the `sa` password is: `setup.exe /SAPWD`. [Install SQL Server from the Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15). Does `SQLEXPR.exe /?` via `cmd.exe` list anything?

Comment: Turns out it's because some computers authenticate on a domain and have password complexity requirements.  While others use local authentication.

Comment: I would like to know what all the facility code meanings are though.  As this is an installer and I would like to know how it might otherwise fail.  It seems it's not enough just to check the errorcode

Comment: For this case I would argue that the executable you're running is not returning a correct error code. From the error description, it seems that the low 16 bits should be 0x52D (1325, `ERROR_PASSWORD_RESTRICTION`). Don't know what facility code 1204 (0x4B4) means, unless the executable is (incorrectly) using the high 16 bits to refer to the Windows error code (1204 == `ERROR_BAD_PROVIDER`).